# Python- strptime ValueError unconverted data remains: :00

Tags: python, csv, strptime

I have a .csv file with a column that have dates which looks like "2/15/2016  1:44:00 PM",am running into following error with the code below...can anyone provide inputs on what is wrong?

CODE:-

```
import csv
import datetime as dt
import os

File = 'C:/Users/Alan Cedeno/Desktop/Test_Folder/HiSAM1_data_160215_164858.csv'
root, ext = os.path.splitext(File)
output = root + '-new.csv'
with open(File,'r') as csvinput,open(output, 'w') as csvoutput:

    writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
    reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

    all = []
    row = next(reader)
    for line in reader:
        row.append(dt.datetime.strptime(line[0],'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').time())
        all.append(row)

    for row in reader:
        row.append(row[0])
        all.append(row)

    writer.writerows(all)
```

ERROR -

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\alance~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpujjfa2.py in <module>()
     14         row = next(reader)
     15         for line in reader:
---> 16             row.append(dt.datetime.strptime(line[0],'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))
     17             all.append(row)
     18 

C:\Users\Alan Cedeno\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-   1.6.1.3253.win-x86_64\lib\_strptime.pyc in _strptime(data_string, format)
    326     if len(data_string) != found.end():
    327         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
--> 328                           data_string[found.end():])
    329 
    330     year = None

ValueError: unconverted data remains: :00
```

Here is a screenshot of the Data-

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the information in the question and the traceback given in comments, your datetime format string is incomplete - missing seconds, should be:

```
%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S
```

Comment: I have tried it and it gave me this ValueError: time data '2/15/2016 13:44:00' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:S %p' 
 I have updated the question with an image of the data.

Comment: @AlanCedeno watch the `%` before the `S`.

Comment: now it gives me this error  ValueError: time data '2/15/2016 13:44:00' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p'

Comment: @AlanCedeno okay, `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S` should work, check it out.

Comment: I was getting this error because of a typo. I was using %y . So I changed it to %Y and it worked.