# Python datetime. ValueError: unconverted data remains: +00

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a data string that comes from a data set into a datetime object and I am getting the following error,

This error is quite different than others I saw on other questions like [Python- strptime ValueError unconverted data remains: :00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36169304/python-strptime-valueerror-unconverted-data-remains-00)

```
import datetime

date_ = '2021-08-31 21:14:39.901557+00'
source_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

My error

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: +00
```

Comment: From what I see `+00` isn't supported. What **is** supported is `+0000` using `%z` as the UTC offset. But `+00` is not a valid UTC offset. Here is the relevant documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: You could do `re.sub(r'([+]\d\d)$', r'\g<1>00', date_)` to ensure that the UTC offset is valid. assuming that when the minutes are missing it is because they are `00`

Answer (score 2):

as @Bakuriu mentioned this is invalid

```
date_ = '2021-08-31 21:14:39.901557+00'
```

To fix it you should add the remaining zeros and add a %z to the strptime

```
date_ = '2021-08-31 21:14:39.901557+0000'
source_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
```